# Web Scraping, data keywords

Tags: search, web-scraping, web-crawler, bots

i want to crawl a web site, by finding some specific data on it. Does web scraper support keyword properties, for example: i want to extract all data containing the words Java, PHP developper. Is there some web crawlers which can support these properties ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no special keyword scrapers. Yet you might imitate them.

### Case 1

You suppose the html head section `meta` contains keywords:

```
<html> 
   <head>
      <meta name="keywords" content="java, php, python, linux">
   <head>
<html>
```

1. Scrape not the whole web page but rather a part of it - 1st 1000 characters.

2. Check this part for keywords. Use [regex](https://webscraping.pro/regex-expressions/) for it, for ex. `/java|php|linux|python/gi`
3. If found, mark/save this url and use it for thourought scrape in future.

### Case 2

No meta with keywords in interest on web pages. :-(
Just make a regular page content retrieving, using regex (see above) for keywords presence check in the whole page text.